# $option in Rediect->toRoute() use for what?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas

I have a question about Controller Plugin: Redirect.php

I have already read about it but still don't understand clearly

```
/**
     * Generate redirect response based on given route
     *
     * @param  string $route RouteInterface name
     * @param  array $params Parameters to use in url generation, if any
     * @param  array $options RouteInterface-specific options to use in url generation, if any
     * @param  bool $reuseMatchedParams Whether to reuse matched parameters
     * @return Response
     * @throws Exception\DomainException if composed controller does not implement InjectApplicationEventInterface, or
     *         router cannot be found in controller event
     */
    public function toRoute($route = null, $params = [], $options = [], $reuseMatchedParams = false)
```

I understand what $route and $params but dont understand $options use for what.

What are RouteInterface-sprecific options?

So can anybody explain it for me? and pls give me some examples about it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

There may be other uses but I only use the force_canonical option to display a full url address:

```
$url_confirm = $this->url()->fromRoute('login',
                    [
                        'action' => 'confirm',
                        'id' => $user->token
                    ], [
                        'force_canonical' => true
                    ]);
```

This link can then be sent by email or SMS to a user ...

Answer (score 1):

The list of possible options for `assemble()` by route type:

1. Chain

   - `has_child`: used to force passing `has_child` to all chained routes.
2. Hostname

   - `uri`: you can pass as `Laminas\Uri\Uri` object here and the host name of the route will get populated into that object as host name
3. Literal

   - none
4. Method

   - none
5. Part

   - `has_child`: force assembling part route as it would have child routes.
   - `translator`: used to pass the translator instance for translated routes
   - `locale`: the locale which with the route should be translated (note this can come from the parameter too). This could be useful if you like to link from one language version to another.
   - all other options from TreeRouteStack
6. Placeholder:

   - none
7. Regex

   - none
8. Scheme

   - `uri`: you can pass as `Laminas\Uri\Uri` object here and the scheme of the route will get populated into that object as scheme
9. Segment:

   - `has_child`: see above
   - `translator`: see above
   - `text_domain`: text domain for translation (e.g. for Gettext)
   - `locale`: see above
10. Wildcard

    - none
11. TreeRouteStack

    - `uri`: you can pass your own `Laminas\Uri\Uri` instance here
    - `force_canonical`: return full URI with scheme, host and port
    - `query`: append query string
    - `fragment`: add fragment to URI
    - `normalize_path`: normalize URI see `Laminas\Uri\Uri::normalize()`
    - `only_return_path`: only assemble the return path, without further doing some work on the path (no `force_canonical` or normalization etc.

Usually also the name of the route is passed as option to the routes. Of cause the Redirect/Url plugin does this for you.